# Share a video to Vimeo on iOS 7

Tags: ios

How does one share a video to Vimeo using the added support to the social framework on iOS 7?

This seems pretty new, haven't found any info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what's called `UIActivityViewController`, available on iOS 6 and later. Based on `initWithActivityItems` it automatically decides what type of content you want to share and handles the rest. Pretty cool when used properly.

```
- (IBAction)showShareSheet:(id)sender {

    NSArray *objects = @[moviePlayer.contentURL];

    UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                          initWithActivityItems:objects
                                          applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activity animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: @Helium3 haven't seen those in iOS 7, because as far as I'm concerned the `UIActivityViewController` is responsible for Vimeo now and I'm pretty sure you can't access it like you could access Twitter back in the day in iOS 5.